# Android QT Development with Java - Alternatives?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, qt-jambi

Is it only possible to write an Android application with QT using the Android NDK?
(The QT Jambi development seems to be dead.. No releases for the year '13)

Are there alternative multi platform frameworks for coding Android applications with Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there alternative multi platform frameworks for coding Android applications with Java?

The short is answer is no.

Qt Jambi is supposed to be the main framework for it, so if it does not work for you for some reason, that is about it. You can try to step up and participate, however.

(That being said, you have not mentioned what would not work, just that it had no release in 2013.)

Comment: So, QT Jambi doesn't support the mobile platform and therefore I can't develop an Android application with the current Out-of-the-box version of QT Jambi with Java code. Correct? So I have to write my own wrapper classes or something else if I want to use Java?

Comment: I would say, it is better to contribute to the Qt Jambi project if it does not work for you. That way, it will be usable for others, too, and the next person will not ask the same question again...

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the Android SDK? (you can use the Eclipse plugin or Android Studio) which are great.

Comment: They'd like to have the possibility to simply port the android application (or parts of them) on a computer. That's the reason why I'm looking for a multi platform framework.

Comment: This should have been a comment once you have enough reputation. This does not really attempt to answer the question.